# MySQL after update trigger - hidden syntax error

Tags: mysql, triggers, syntax-error

the following trigger cannot be created on my local testing db (MySQL 5.6) and I do not understand why.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER write_status_history AFTER UPDATE ON request
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE snew CHAR;
    DECLARE sold CHAR;
    DECLARE unew CHAR;
    DECLARE uold CHAR;

    -- Status change
    IF NEW.status <> OLD.status THEN
        SET unew = (SELECT username FROM ta_users WHERE id = NEW.ta_users_id);
        SET snew = (SELECT name FROM status WHERE id = NEW.status);
        SET sold = (SELECT name FROM status WHERE id = OLD.status);
        INSERT INTO history (`request_id`, `content`) 
        VALUES(NEW.id, CONCAT('Statuswechsel von ', sold, ' nach ', snew, ' durchgeführt von ', user, '.'));
    -- User change
    ELSE IF NEW.ta_users_id <> OLD.ta_users_id THEN
        SET unew = (SELECT username FROM ta_users WHERE id = NEW.ta_users_id);
        SET uold = (SELECT username FROM ta_users WHERE id = OLD.ta_users_id);
        INSERT INTO history (`request_id`, `content`) 
        VALUES(NEW.id, CONCAT('Bearbeiter gewechselt von ', uold, ' nach ', unew, '.'));
    END IF;
END
//

DELIMITER ;
```

I get this error messsage indicating a syntax error if I attempt to launch the query:

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 21.
```

MySQL Workbench, however, reports `Syntax Error: missing 'if'` when hovering over the last `END`.

Do you have an idea how to fix this syntax error? I already tried adding a semicolon to the last `END`, that didn't help - same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysql `else-if` would be as

`elseif`

When you give a space it will consider `else` and then another `if` and will expect the inner `if` to be closed.